# Reading Multiple Digit after character

Tags: c, string, integer

I have tried this code which takes in the input of the initial coordinate (x,y). Then gets a String of the form N3 E2 etc. Where N denotes north E is East, W is West and S is South. The output should be the final coordinates

**Input Format**: 
The first line will contain the initial x, y co-ordinates of the robot separated by a space. The second line will contain the list of commands each separated by a space.

**Boundary Conditions**: List of commands is of length from 2 to 200.

**Output Format**: The final x, y co-ordinates of the robot separated by a space.

**Example Input/Output**:

**Input**:

```
0 0 
E9 N6
```

**Output**:

```
9 6
```

**Explanation**: The robot moves 9 units in East direction and then moves 6 units in North direction.

Now I have tried the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char s[1000], alp[1000];
int num[1000],a,c;
int i, k = 0, m, n;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&c);
getchar();// To get the newline after the coordinates
//Read string until newline character is encountered
if (scanf("%999[^\n]", s) == 1) {
    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        n = 1;
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)s[i])) {
            alp[k] = s[i];  // store the letter
            for (n = s[i+1] - '0'; isdigit((unsigned char)s[i+2]); i++) {
                 n = n * 10 + s[i+1] - '0';
            }
            num[k] = n;   // store the number
            k += 1;
        }
 }
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    printf("num[%d] = %d alp[%d] = %c\n",i,num[i],i,alp[i]);    
    switch(alp[i]){
    case 'N': c += num[i];
    break;
    case 'S': c -= num[i];
    break;
    case 'E':a += num[i]; 
    break;
    case 'W':a -= num[i];
    break;
        }
    }
}
printf("\nNEW : %d %d",a,c); //Prints the output
putchar('\n');
return 0;
}
```

The `num` array stores the values of the distance to be moved in the particular direction which is stored in the `alp` array
Now this code works for single digit moves like N3 E2 W4 etc but for input like

```
N10 W20 S200
```

I am not getting the values stored in the `num` array as expected. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a much simple way, you could just do like this:

```
char dir, blank;
int num;
while (scanf("%c%d%c", &dir, &num, &blank) != EOF) {
    // do anything
}
```

And if you want to keep the input commands in one line:

```
do {
    scanf("%c%d%c", &dir, &num, &blank);
    // do anything
} while (blank != '\n');
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I never think of the simple ways to solve. It's so simple now. I did it with the `do while` loop.